# Game stuck on first frame when triggered by onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick

I'm making a game in a webpage using the html canvas element, and I have put all of the code for my game inside of a function called playPong(), and when the code is not stored inside of a function, it works perfectly fine, but when the function is called from the onclick event, all of the elements of the game show, but nothing happens. This is my code.

```html
<canvas id='my' width = '640' height = '480'></canvas>
<script>
function playPong() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("my");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function paddle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedModifier = 0;
    this.hasCollidedWith = function(ball) {
        var paddleLeftWall = this.x;
        var paddleRightWall = this.x + this.width;
        var paddleTopWall = this.y;
        var paddleBottomWall = this.y + this.height;
        if (ball.x > paddleLeftWall &&
            ball.x < paddleRightWall &&
            ball.y > paddleTopWall &&
            ball.y < paddleBottomWall) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    this.move = function(keyCode) {
        var nextY = this.y;
        if (keyCode == 40) {
            nextY += 5;
            this.speedModifer = 1.5;
        } else if (keyCode == 38) {
            nextY += -5;
            this.speedModifier = 1.5;
        } else {
            this.speedModifier = 0;
        }
        nextY = nextY < 0 ? 0 : nextY;
        nextY = nextY + this.height > 480 ? 480 - this.height : nextY;
        this.y = nextY;
    };
}
var player = new paddle(5, 200, 25, 100);
var ai = new paddle(610, 200, 25, 100);
var ball = {
    x: 320,
    y: 240,
    radius: 7,
    xSpeed: 2,
    ySpeed: 0,
    playerscore: 0,
    aiscore: 0,
    reverseX: function() {
        this.xSpeed *= -1;
    },
    reverseY: function() {
        this.ySpeed *= -1;
    },
    reset: function() {
        alert('The score is now ' + this.playerscore + ' to ' + this.aiscore);
        this.x = 20;
        this.y = 24;
        this.xSpeed = 2;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
        
    },
    isBouncing: function() {
        return ball.ySpeed != 0;
    },
    modifyXSpeedBy: function(modification) {
        modification = this.xSpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        var nextValue = this.xSpeed + modification;
        nextValue = Math.abs(nextValue) > 9 ? 9 : nextValue;
        this.xSpeed = nextValue;
    },
    modifyYSpeedBy: function(modification) {
        modification = this.ySpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        this.ySpeed += modification;
    }
};

function tick() {
    updateGame();
    draw()
    window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000 / 60);
}

function updateGame() {
    ball.x += ball.xSpeed;
    ball.y += ball.ySpeed;
    if (ball.x < 0) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.aiscore = ball.aiscore + 1;
        
    }
    if (ball.x > 640) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.playerscore = ball.playerscore + 1
        
    }
    if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= 480) {
        ball.reverseY();
    }
    var collidedWithPlayer = player.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    var collidedWithAi = ai.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    if (collidedWithPlayer || collidedWithAi) {
        ball.reverseX();
        ball.modifyXSpeedBy(0.25);
        var speedUpValue = collidedWithPlayer ? player.speedModifier : ai.speedModifier;
        ball.modifyYSpeedBy(speedUpValue);
    }
    for (var keyCode in heldDown) {
        player.move(keyCode);
    }
    var aiMiddle = ai.y + (ai.height / 2);
    if (aiMiddle < ball.y) {
        ai.move(40);
    }
    if (aiMiddle > ball.y) {
        ai.move(38);
    }
    
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    renderPaddle(player);
    renderPaddle(ai);
    renderBall(ball);
}

function renderPaddle(paddle) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
}

function renderBall(ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fill();
}
var heldDown = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(keyInfo) {
    heldDown[event.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(keyInfo) {
    delete heldDown[event.keyCode];
}, false);
tick();
}


</script>



<script>
function getOff(){
alert ("you've been on for five minutes now. Time to take a break.");
setTimeout(function(){ alert("it's been 10 minutes now. Get back to work.");
close();
var body = document.getElementById('hide5')
body.style.display = 'none'
},300000);
}
setInterval (getOff, 300000)
 
}
</script> 

<button onclick = 'playPong()'> Play pong </button>
```

Comment: Please send the code in line 178. I think it has a syntax bug

Comment: ? there is no code in line 178.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start game by button. You can create function playPong() to cover just tick() code line.

Like below.

```html
<canvas id='my' width = '640' height = '480'></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("my");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function paddle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedModifier = 0;
    this.hasCollidedWith = function(ball) {
        var paddleLeftWall = this.x;
        var paddleRightWall = this.x + this.width;
        var paddleTopWall = this.y;
        var paddleBottomWall = this.y + this.height;
        if (ball.x > paddleLeftWall &&
            ball.x < paddleRightWall &&
            ball.y > paddleTopWall &&
            ball.y < paddleBottomWall) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    this.move = function(keyCode) {
        var nextY = this.y;
        if (keyCode == 40) {
            nextY += 5;
            this.speedModifer = 1.5;
        } else if (keyCode == 38) {
            nextY += -5;
            this.speedModifier = 1.5;
        } else {
            this.speedModifier = 0;
        }
        nextY = nextY < 0 ? 0 : nextY;
        nextY = nextY + this.height > 480 ? 480 - this.height : nextY;
        this.y = nextY;
    };
}
var player = new paddle(5, 200, 25, 100);
var ai = new paddle(610, 200, 25, 100);
var ball = {
    x: 320,
    y: 240,
    radius: 7,
    xSpeed: 2,
    ySpeed: 0,
    playerscore: 0,
    aiscore: 0,
    reverseX: function() {
        this.xSpeed *= -1;
    },
    reverseY: function() {
        this.ySpeed *= -1;
    },
    reset: function() {
        alert('The score is now ' + this.playerscore + ' to ' + this.aiscore);
        this.x = 20;
        this.y = 24;
        this.xSpeed = 2;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
        
    },
    isBouncing: function() {
        return ball.ySpeed != 0;
    },
    modifyXSpeedBy: function(modification) {
        modification = this.xSpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        var nextValue = this.xSpeed + modification;
        nextValue = Math.abs(nextValue) > 9 ? 9 : nextValue;
        this.xSpeed = nextValue;
    },
    modifyYSpeedBy: function(modification) {
        modification = this.ySpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        this.ySpeed += modification;
    }
};

function tick() {
    updateGame();
    draw()
    window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000 / 60);
}

function updateGame() {
    ball.x += ball.xSpeed;
    ball.y += ball.ySpeed;
    if (ball.x < 0) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.aiscore = ball.aiscore + 1;
        
    }
    if (ball.x > 640) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.playerscore = ball.playerscore + 1
        
    }
    if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= 480) {
        ball.reverseY();
    }
    var collidedWithPlayer = player.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    var collidedWithAi = ai.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    if (collidedWithPlayer || collidedWithAi) {
        ball.reverseX();
        ball.modifyXSpeedBy(0.25);
        var speedUpValue = collidedWithPlayer ? player.speedModifier : ai.speedModifier;
        ball.modifyYSpeedBy(speedUpValue);
    }
    for (var keyCode in heldDown) {
        player.move(keyCode);
    }
    var aiMiddle = ai.y + (ai.height / 2);
    if (aiMiddle < ball.y) {
        ai.move(40);
    }
    if (aiMiddle > ball.y) {
        ai.move(38);
    }
    
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    renderPaddle(player);
    renderPaddle(ai);
    renderBall(ball);
}

function renderPaddle(paddle) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
}

function renderBall(ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fill();
}
var heldDown = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(keyInfo) {
    heldDown[event.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(keyInfo) {
    delete heldDown[event.keyCode];
}, false);
function playPong(){
    tick();
}



</script>



<script>
function getOff(){
alert ("you've been on for five minutes now. Time to take a break.");
setTimeout(function(){ alert("it's been 10 minutes now. Get back to work.");
close();
var body = document.getElementById('hide5')
body.style.display = 'none'
},300000);
}
setInterval (getOff, 300000)
 
}
</script> 

<button onclick = 'playPong()'> Play pong </button>
```